# Content of url - affect on conversions

Tags: url

No sure if this is the right q & a to post this question, let me  know which is appropriate if not. I was just telling my dad that a link like 'my blog about x' is more likely to be clicked on than something like 'click here' or 'this blog'. I then unsuccessfully tried and find some studies which either do or don't confirm this theory. Does anyone know of any studies that look at likelyhood of a user clicking on a link based on it's content?
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

User can only guess the content. You can just try your self - create 2 landing pages on your blog, and show different links & descriptions randomly (50-50). You will know who is right very soon ;-)